# Get mouse cursor property on click in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a simple react jsx file where I render some text. I have its corresponding css file too where I define what happens when the mouse hovers over a certain text.

I want to access these cursor properties when I perform a click operation anywhere on the screen. I want to check at the point of click if my cursor had a property like 'text' or if it had any other value.

I'm currently trying to use

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
      if (e.relatedTarget.style.cursor = 'text') {
        console.log('this is OUT !');
      }
    });
```

but this doesn't work as expect and the value always returns `""`.

How can I access my cursor property when I click anywhere in the file?

Comment: `if (e.relatedTarget.style.cursor = 'text') {` If you want to compare something, you need at least 2 `=` signs (`if (e.relatedTarget.style.cursor == 'text') {`)

Comment: `e.currentTarget` should let you get the element that has been clicked for synthetic events. Tim's comment above should be immediately helpful though.

Comment: If my understanding of your use-case is right, you can use `useRef` hook and add a click handler to the container. Then you can check if your target element is clicked. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/click-detection-with-useref-5deh4) is an example. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried out changing ```=``` to ```===```, but it still isn't giving me the desired result. @Awolf I'm going to try the useRef hook and update.

Comment: turns out I didn't have to complicate it so much. I found that I could get my cursor properties by calling ```getComputedStyle(event.target)``` inside my event listener. Thanks again for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have to complicate it so much. I found that I could get my cursor properties by calling `getComputedStyle(event.target)` inside my event listener. So my event listener changed to

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
      const { cursor } = getComputedStyle(e.target);
      // logic based on cursor value
    });
```